# React Dropdown component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown

Can anybody suggest me a good React dropdown component, which is flexible and by flexible I mean that I want to draw more than just a list into the dropdown. Most of the components or actually all of them work i a way that one creates a react component...lets call it Dropdown and then give it some parameters like the default value, the list you want to render inside it and so on. But I want to create more to it. Pseudo example:

```
<Dropdown>
  <SelectedItem>
     Selected item value, that is always visible
  </SelectedItem>
  <List>
     <ListItem/>
     ...
     this is a scrollable part
  </List>
  <footer>
     Some epic stuff, that is outside of the list and is not part of
     the scrollable area
  </footer>
</Dropdown>
```

List and Footer would be in part of the dropdown which visibility is toggled.

Does anybody know a working component that can handle this functionality? Im really do not want to write this dropdown from scratch...Done it before with some angular/jquery mix and I have seen the bug count that may come with this... So I am hoping to find some component that has already solved those problems.

Answer (score 1):

React-select (https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) is a very flexible component for drop-downs. You can pass a function in some properties for rendering different parts of the dropdown: menuRenderer, valueRenderer and optionRenderer.

Comment: I did try this and I actually somehow missed those rendered parts...This should hopefully do the trick.